Running Total in SQL Without New Table, Partition, or CTE
I am trying to write a SQL query in Fishbowl, an environment that limits common query functions. The table I am working with has the following columns:
PART   QTY    DATE
 AB     1    2024-01-09
 AB    -7    2024-04-13
 AB     9    2024-08-19
 PL     0    2024-03-10
…       …      …

I want to calculate the running total of qty like:
PART  QTYcumul  DATE
 AB      1     2024-01-09
 AB     -6     2024-04-13
 AB      3     2024-08-19
 PL      0     2024-03-10

And so on. The tricky part is that Fishbowl is NOT compatible with

Temporary Tables
CTEs (with as tables)
summing with OVER or PARTITION
declaring new variables

For example, I CANNOT do
Sum(qty) over(partition by part) as qtycumul

I also CANNOT do
Declare @qtycum int

I also CANNOT do
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE runningtotal (…)

A lot of what I find online uses summing up with over and partition to do running totals. The system CAN sum a whole column, but it CANNOT partition it.
What are some other creative ways I could go about this?
I have tried using CTEs, temporary tables, and new variables, but the Fishbowl environment doesn’t know how to handle those and returns

ERROR CODE 1064; You have an error in your SQL Syntax in line_____

in the line with the new table creation, SUM OVER, etco

Can you do views?

Just replace all the places where you might have used a CTE or temporary table with a subquery. Since you don't have CTE, you may have to duplicate some subqueries.

If you don't have window functions, you'll just need some more subqueries that use GROUP BY.

Window functions and CTE are relatively recent additions to many SQL implementations, what do you think we did before we had them?

By the way, why work with such a bad tool with this poor functionality? Get rid of it and use something better.

See example, where window function replaced by "classic" subquery or  join and group by.
May be, this is works in your case. I can not test any query in Fishbowl.
Window function
select *
  ,sum(qty)over(partition by part order by date)qtyCumulative
from test t

Similarly with the subquery
select *
  ,(select sum(qty) from test t2 
              where t2.part=t.part -- partition by part
                  and t2.date<=t.date -- rows unbounded preceding order by date
    ) qtyCumulative
from test t

Or self JOIN and GROUP BY.
There, for example, partition by PART
and  order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding (condition <)
select t1.part,t1.date
   ,min(t1.qty)+coalesce(sum(t2.qty),0) qtyCumulative
from test t1
left join test t2 on t1.part=t2.part and t2.date<t1.date
group by t1.part,t1.date
order by t1.part,t1.date

with test data as
create table test (PART varchar(2), QTY int, DATE date);
insert into test values
 ('AB',     1    ,'2024-01-09')
,('AB',    -7    ,'2024-04-13')
,('AB',     9    ,'2024-08-19')
,('PL',     0    ,'2024-03-10')
;

output is



part
date
qty
qtyCumulative




AB
2024-01-09
1
1


AB
2024-04-13
-7
-6


AB
2024-08-19
9
3


PL
2024-03-10
0
0



Difference may be if rows have date matches.
Example

Is there a way to daisy-chain the table creation rather than using the CREATE table function (which is unavailable)? For instance, nesting a SELECT FROM (make t2 here) as t2 instead

Why do you need to create a table? You already have a table with the data. Replace the name of the table name test in query with your table name and try.

select * into your_table from (
select 'AB' PART  ,   1 as QTY ,  '2024-01-09' as 'DATE'
union
select 'AB' PART,    -7 as QTY ,   '2024-04-13' as 'DATE'
union
select 'AB' PART,     9 as QTY ,   '2024-08-19' as 'DATE'
union
select 'PL' PART,     0 as QTY ,   '2024-03-10' as 'DATE'
union
select 'PL' PART,     0 as QTY ,   '2024-03-11' as 'DATE'
)a
SELECT
t1.PART,
t1. DATE,
ISNULL(SUM(t2.QTY), 0) AS qtycumul
FROM
your_table t1
LEFT JOIN
your_table t2 ON t1.DATE >= t2.DATE and t1.PART=t2.PART
GROUP BY
t1.PART,t1.DATE
ORDER BY
t1.PART,t1.DATE

You should learn about the difference between UNION and UNION ALL

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Is there a way to do this when there are many more parts and dates? I will probably have 2,000-3,000 total to parse
